# Programatically changing one EditText color changes EditTexts color in whole app using Android 5

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have very strange problem in Android 5. If user inputs something wrong I want to set error to edittext and change it color to red, and when user starts typing something I want to change color back to green. This is how i do it:

```
eText.setError(message);
    eText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    eText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            eText.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                    ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_green), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

In lower android versions than 5, everything works perfect, but not in Lollipop. If I change one edittext color, all edittexts in all app changes it color. Is there any way to fix this strange thing? Or it is some of material design and Android 5 tricks which I don't know?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the background `Drawable` is reused across many Views. To ensure the `Drawable` is not shared between multiple Views you should use the `mutate` method.

See: [mutate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate())

**Example code:**

```
Drawable background = mainMenuButton.getBackground();
background.mutate();
background.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
mainMenuButton.setBackground(background);
```

[Android 5.0 Lollipop: setColorFilter "leaks" onto other buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015811/android-5-0-lollipop-setcolorfilter-leaks-onto-other-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Do Same for like spinner colour changes..

In Android Lollipop Version you have to implement code for kitkat version and lollipop version separately , please do this code for change background of spinner. its example of image background changes of images.

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT => Build.VERSION_CODES.KitKat) 
                        {
                            //for Lollipop Vession
                      // do on textChangeListner code
eText.setBackgroundDrawable(Color.RED);
                        }
                        else
                        {
     // do on textChangeListner code
eText.setBackgroundResource(Color.RED);
                        }
```

i hope it helps you, if it is useful code for then please mark me .. Thanx.. :)

Comment: So how to change color in Lollipop and not to change all edit text colors? This is the question..

Comment: @Eddwhis :- if you want to change color of edit text then you have implement  eText.setBackgroundColor not get method use.