# Android: Change Tint Color of a single EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I found various answers on how to change the line color of an EditText in Android programatically. 
Right now I'm using this solution:

```
    final Drawable originalDrawable = editText.getBackground();
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, ColorStateList.valueOf(darkVibrantColor));
    editText.setBackground(wrappedDrawable);
```

This does in fact change to color of an EditText, but unfortunately it does not only change the line color of the specific EditText I'm using but the line color of all EditTexts used in my application. Event if they are in different activities.

How do I change the line color of just one specific EditText without changing the line color globally? Thanks.

Update: I cannot use a predefined style as the color is generated dynamically while the application is running.

Comment: you can create style for your editText view

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34004110/5744335) given in stackoverflow

Comment: I must change the color programatically not by using a style. I updated the question.

Comment: I have posted solution below, hope it helps you. Let me know if it doesn't. @Androidicus

Answer (score 0):

Try this, could help you

In your style.xml

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

in you edittext add your style

```
<EditText  
    style="@style/MyEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Subject"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately,  I have to change the color programatically as the color is generated from an image while the app is running. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided code to *programmatically change underline color of EditText*.

```
EditText editTextOne=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_one);
Drawable drawable=editTextOne.getBackground();
int color=Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
    editTextOne.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    editTextOne.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,drawable,null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that didn't work either. EditText changes color, but EditText in different activity changes color as well.

Comment: I had tested this code, it doesn't change underline color of EditText in other activity. Are you using custom EditText? @Androidicus

Comment: @Arhsak No I'm using the standard EditText implementation. Mutating the drawable did work, as I've posted below. No idea why your solution didn't work for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It's posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33148980/3449811) (not accepted) answer. The trick is to mutate the background drawable after it is retrieved from the EditText.

Here's my working code:

```
final Drawable originalDrawable = editText.getBackground();
originalDrawable.mutate();
final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, ColorStateList.valueOf(darkVibrantColor));
editText.setBackground(wrappedDrawable);
```